# send email to user register using php

Tags: php, mysql, email-validation

I'm building a registration form using MySQL to store data and work perfectly. when users register will be sent a verification email to activate user accounts. the problem is not the verification email sent to the email users but user data and the activation code can get into mysql.

Here code for **insert.php**

```
<?php
    //panggil file config.php untuk menghubung ke server
    include('config.php');

    //tangkap data dari form
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
    $telp = $_POST['telp'];
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    // regular expression for email check
    $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/';
    if(preg_match($regex, $email))
    { 
        $password=md5($password); // encrypted password
        $activation=md5($email.time()); // encrypted email+timestamp
        $count=mysql_query("SELECT id_user FROM user WHERE email='$email'");
        // email check
        if(mysql_num_rows($count) < 1)
        {
            $query = mysql_query("insert into user (nama,email,telp,password,alamat,username,activation) VALUES('$nama', '$email', '$telp', '$password', '$alamat', '$username', '$activation')") or die(mysql_error());
            if ($query) 
            {
                header('location:index.php');
            }
            // sending email
            include ('sendEmail.php');

            $to=$email;
            $subject="Email verification";
            $body='Hi, <br/> <br/> Silakan verifikasi dengan klik link di bawah ini. <br/> <br/> <a href="http://localhost/LAPAN-Project/verify.php?code=' . $activation . '">Verifikasi</a>';

            sendEmail($to,$subject,$body);
            $msg= "Registration successful, please activate email."; 
        }
        else
        {
            $msg= 'The email is already taken, please try new.'; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.'; 
    }
    // HTML Part
//}
?>
```

and here the code **sendEmail.php**

```
<?php
function sendEmail($to,$subject,$body)
{
    require ('class.phpmailer.php');
    $from       = "me@kumistebal.web.id";
    $mail       = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(true);            // use SMTP
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP host
    $mail->Port       =  465;                    // set the SMTP port
    $mail->Username   = "*********@gmail.com";  // SMTP  username
    $mail->Password   = "*********";  // SMTP password
    $mail->SetFrom($from, 'From Name');
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from,'From Name');
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $address = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $to);

    if(!$mail->Send())
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    else
        echo "Message has been sent";
}    

?>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do?

Comment: Is it showing any error on that page? I think you need to do few changes in your `php.ini` file while sending mail using SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP host`

just use

`$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP host`

Comment: you are using gmail as the host and the email id is `me@kumistebal.web.id` I think u need to use some gmail id to send the email

Answer (score 0):

You need to change host  with $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP host and  $mail->Port =25; // set the SMTP port